# Reducible ODE when depends only of $y'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this ODE: 
$$y''=\sqrt{1+(y')^2}$$

I've learned only 4 cases of reducible ODE: when $y''$ depends only on $x$, only on $y$, not depends on $x$ and not depends on $y$. What is the process to solve ODE's which $y''$ depends only on $y'$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not parametrize $y'(t)=\sinh(\phi(t))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let u= y'.  Then the equation becomes $u'= \sqrt{1+ u^2}$.  That is separable as $\frac{du}{\sqrt{1+ u^2}}= dx$.  Integrate to find u(x) then integrate again to find y(x).